# Возможно ли запустить в Linux приложение написанное(и скомпилированное) в MS Visual Studio .net?

Tags: c#, linux, .net

Возможно ли запустить в Linux существующее приложение, написанное(и скомпилированное) в MS Visual Studio .net? Без необходимости запускать его на виртуальном Windows и без Windows-эмулятора типа Wine. Доступ к исходному коду приложения есть

Comment: если достаточно одного слова в качестве ответа, то ответ: нет.

Comment: В Visual Studio можно много чего скомпилировать. К примеру, там можно собрать WPF приложение. Вы бы уточнили свой вопрос.

Comment: На каком языке написан исходный код?

Comment: Nikolay, в тэгах присутствует C#

Comment: И правда. не по глазам :)

Answer (score 7):

Да, для этого есть [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/). Проект можно компилировать как компилятором, который входит в Mono, так и в Visual Studio в Windows. Естественно, существует масса важных ограничений. Например, MVC 4 под Mono не работает (работает MVC 5 aka vNext). Обычно, OSS проекты прямо указывают, работает ли фреймворк под Mono или нет.

На дебиане это бы выглядело так

> sudo apt-get install mono
>
> mono MySuperApp.exe

Comment: wine реализует WinAPI на чужеродной для этого API системе, для чего ему приходится эмулировать кучу вещей, вроде структуры файловой системы. Mono - это всего лишь альтернативная реализация CLR, которая не скрывает от программы, на какой ОС она запущена. Программы, работая под Mono, видят "обычные" пути, могут вызывать через P/Invoke линуксовые библиотеки и т.п.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не спора ради, а из чистого интереса. вот обращается упомянутый автором скомпилированный на ms/windows бинарник, интерпретируемый *mono*-й, к `coredll.dll`, как в [первом примере](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx). откуда *mono* возьмёт для него эту библиотеку? p.s. если не трудно, упоминайте меня в ответе, чтоб я получал уведомления.

Comment: @alexander barakin, ниоткуда. `Mono` выкинет `DllNotFoundException` для такого кода.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, т.е., если я правильно понимаю, в программе может встретиться платформо-специфичный код, и в этом случае ответ на изначальный вопрос будет: «нет». если я понял правильно, мне кажется, это существенная оговорка, которую стоит добавить в ответ. p.s. ещё вспоминается про некие `winforms`. кажется, с ними тоже какие-то проблемы есть у *mono*?

Comment: @alexander barakin, цитирую: "Доступ к исходному коду приложения есть".

Comment: @PavelMayorov, т.е., надо будет перекомпилировать (и даже вносить исправления в исходники)? я думаю, это тоже существенная оговорка, которую тоже стоит добавить в ответ. особенно учитывая заголовок вопроса: ведь там явно сказано «и скомпилированное». p.s. а насчёт *winforms* я не ошибся?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin странно ожидать что приложение явно ссылающееся на отсутствующую в системе библиотеку заработает без нее. Например, у меня есть чистое .net приложение с pinvoke на mysupernative.dll. Оно не заработает на соседней машине с Windows. Так что же, в общем случае ответ на вопрос "а можно ли скомпилированный exe запустить на другой машине c Windows?" ответ должен быть "нет", ну или "да, но со значительными оговорками"? В для Mono оговорок вагон и тележка. Причем большинство из них вызваны тем, что mono - это не эмулятор.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin можно внести изменения в исходники (если придется) в VS под Windows, скомпилировать в VS под Windows, запустить под linux - точно как описано в заголовке. Сама по себе *перекопмиляция на linux под linux* не нужна. Если не дергается ничего platform specific - достаточно просто скопировать exe и запустить.

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо за допинформацию. вот вы тоже подтверждаете, что в *.net*-программе вполне может встретиться платформно-специфичный код, который не позволит запустить программу. а что можно прочитать в ответе? мною он воспринимается как «кроме фреймворков, которые могут не работать, больше проблем нет. `mono prog.exe` и всё будет хорошо». вот это я и пытаюсь донести уже четвёртый комментарий подряд.

Comment: @PashaPash. *Например, у меня есть чистое .net приложение с pinvoke на mysupernative.dll. Оно не заработает на соседней машине с Windows. Так что же, в общем случае ответ на вопрос "а можно ли скомпилированный exe запустить на другой машине c Windows?" ответ должен быть "нет", ну или "да, но со значительными оговорками"?* — нет, конечно. если я правильно понимаю ситуацию, то после копирования dll программа заработает и на соседней ms/windows. а вот в gnu/linux она не заработает, куда эту dll ни копируй.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нет, неправильно понимаете. Никаких гарантий что заработает. Копируете с x64 - на x86 - не работает. Копируете с x86 на x64 и у при флаге AnyCPU (default!)- не работает. Копируете dll со ссылкой на рантайм от C++ - не работает. Interop - это механизм вызова с платформозоависимого не-.net кода, Причем платформа тут не в смысле "windows/linux". Использование интеропа - это исключение. Если ТС не написал "есть интероп" - значит его нет. Вы почему-то прочитали вопрос как "можно ли запустить приложение на смеси .net и еще чего-то неизвестного". В вопросе же ничего такого нет.

Comment: Коллеги, я думаю, что надо заканчивать флейм, SO это не форум.

Answer (score 2):

Не так давно, Microsoft сделал часть .NET фреймворка Open Source, в эту часть входит [Core CLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr#get-net-core), на сайте есть инстукции по установке на Linux, хотя такие технологии как WPF, WCF пока не поддерживаются, CLI приложения работать будут!